# Webstorm cannot recognize node Express both on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, express, webstorm

environment:

- Webstorm v10.0.4
- Node.js v0.12.5
- Windows 8.1
- Ubuntu 14.04

Just as the image showing below, on the pannel of creating 'Node.js Express App', Webstorm only finds `Node` and `npm`, but can not recognize `Express`. 
Of course `Express` is installed globally, and I can create a `Express` project via `express-generator` on terminal.

```
➜  ~  npm -g list -depth=0
/usr/local/lib
├── bower@1.4.1
├── cheerio@0.19.0
├── express@4.13.0
├── express-generator@4.12.4
├── npm@2.11.2
└── nrm@0.2.5
```

[image]

And the `idea.log` as follow, not detail messages:

```
[      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
[     93]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: WebStorm (build #WS-141.1550, 12 Jun 2015 00:00) 
[     93]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 8 (6.2, x86) 
[     93]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_40-b26 (Oracle Corporation) 
[     93]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.40-b25 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
[    109]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djb.vmOptions=D:\WebStorm 10.0.4\bin\WebStorm.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:D:\WebStorm 10.0.4\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=WebStorm -Didea.no.jre.check=true -Didea.paths.selector=WebStorm10 
[    281]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (32-bit) in 172 ms 
[    296]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
[    328]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
[   1920]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor js-nashorn-support.xml 
[   3094]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 48 plugins initialized in 1909 ms 
[   3110]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), AngularJS (141.1550), CSS Support, CVS Integration (11), CoffeeScript (2.0), Cucumber.js (141.1550), Dart (141.1550), EJS (141.1550), EditorConfig (1.0), File Watchers (141.1550), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, HAML, HTML Tools (2.0), Handlebars/Mustache (141.1550), IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JSTestDriver Plugin (141.1550), Jade (141.1550), Java Server Pages Integration (1.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), Karma (141.1550), LESS support, LiveEdit (999.0), Meteor (141.1550), NodeJS (141.1550), Perforce Integration (2.0), PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin (141.1550), Polymer & Web Components (141.1550), QuirksMode, REST Client, Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), SASS support, Spy-js (141.1550), Stylus support (141.1550), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TextMate bundles support (VERSION), W3C Validators (2.0), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML, hg4idea (10.0) 
[   4391]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=498008064 
[   4469]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: D:\WebStorm 10.0.4\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
[   4516]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
[   5474]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
[   6709]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63343 
[   8931]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 77 application components initialized in 5758 ms 
[   8965]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 10956 ms 
[   9614]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 16 project components initialized in 258 ms 
[   9614]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
[  17941]   INFO - odejs.packages.NodePackageUtil - Loading node package info for express-generator ... 
[  20427]   INFO - odejs.packages.NodePackageUtil - Info for express-generator node package loaded successfully in 2478.9 ms 
[  21655]   INFO - odejs.packages.NodePackageUtil - Loading node package info for express-generator ... 
[  22243]   INFO - odejs.packages.NodePackageUtil - Info for express-generator node package loaded successfully in 577.0 ms
```

This problem is occured both on Ubuntu and Windows.
Your help is appreciated!

---

Updated:
Just as shown below, I use `nrm` to select the fastest `npm` mirror -- taobao, and `Webstorm` goes wrong with it. When changed back to `npm' main repository,`Webstorm`can fetch`express-generator` info, and everything is OK. Strange!

```
C:\Users\honghe>nrm ls

  npm ---- https://registry.npmjs.org/
  cnpm --- http://r.cnpmjs.org/
* taobao - http://registry.npm.taobao.org/
  edunpm - http://registry.enpmjs.org/
  eu ----- http://registry.npmjs.eu/
  au ----- http://registry.npmjs.org.au/
  sl ----- http://npm.strongloop.com/
  nj ----- https://registry.nodejitsu.com/
  pt ----- http://registry.npmjs.pt/


C:\Users\honghe>nrm test

  npm ---- 1646ms
  cnpm --- 1275ms
* taobao - 4388ms
  edunpm - 994ms
  eu ----- 2422ms
  au ----- 1040ms
  sl ----- 1369ms
  nj ----- 2176ms
  pt ----- Fetch Error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially, WebStorm installs specified version of `express-generator` package in temporary directory. Then WebStorm uses it to generate a new Express project. WebStorm doesn't use already installed `express` or `express-generator` packages.

BTW, `express-generator` always installs `express` package locally to a new project, so already installed `express` packages cannot be reused anyway.

According to the screenshot, the problem is that `Version: Unavailable` (version of `express-generator`). The cause should be specified at the bottom of the dialog, below `CSS` combobox. Not sure, but probably, it might be caused by the lack of the Internet connection. More detailed error description can be found in idea.log (on the main menu "Help | Show Log in Explorer").

Comment: Thank you very much! But there is not error message on the dialog and `idea.log`, just as the updated question. Is anything else I can do?

Comment: Fix the bug, maybe the problem is that `Webstorm` is not compatible with `npm` mirrors. But don't know why. Odd!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! The bug is fixed (well, actually, there were a few bugs ;)). The fix will be available in WebStorm 11 EAP.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question while looking for a resolution. Mine was a syntax error in the 'package.json' file. Either in the main project directory or the node install within Program Files. The IDE doesn't flag the error, it just states that its 'Unavailible'.

To resolve this do the following, open CMD - within the folder for the node instalation, Delete the package.json along with the node_modules folder. (**Ensure the non default ones are backed up so you can get them back**) Then run:

```
npm init
```

This will intialise npm and restore the default packages and package.json. This will in turn restore express-generator.